# regular expression for a number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

It is a regular expression for a number. I have several questions about it.

1. (0U1U2U3U4U5U6U7U8U9)*   Does it means a set containing a number from 0 to 9 and then concatenate itself n times, or a set containing all of those 10 numbers and then concatenate itself n times.
2. Is the first (0U1U2U3U4U5U6U7U8U9) necessary if (0U1U2U3U4U5U6U7U8U9)* means a set containing all of those 10 numbers and then concatenate itself n times.
3. Is this set represent the natural number or only part of the natural number.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression

$$0\cup 1\cup 2\cup 3\cup 4\cup 5\cup 6\cup 7\cup 8\cup 9$$

represents any single digit, including $0$. Call this expression $\rho$. Then $\rho^*$ represents any finite sequence of things matching $\rho$, which in this case means any finite string of digits. Note that *finite* includes *empty*, the string consisting of no digits at all. Thus, $\rho\rho^*$, which is what you have, represents any string consisting of a single digit ($\rho$) followed by any finite (possibly empty) string of digits ($\rho^*$). In other words, $\rho\rho^*$ represents any **non-empty** finite string of digits; the purpose of the initial $\rho$ is to ensure that there is at least one digit.

In words this definition of *number* amounts to saying that a number is any non-empty finite string of digits, where the digits are $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$, and $9$. Note that this definition allows leading zeroes: it allows $00123$ as a number, for instance. It does, however, include all natural numbers, including $0$; indeed, it includes each of them infinitely many times, since it allows any number of leading zeroes.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense to me right now.

Comment: @Bruce: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading up on regular expressions, especially the Kleene star. You mention a variable $ n $ but I'm not sure where you're getting this from.

A Kleene star simply means the argument is repeated some integer amount of times, possibly zero.

For example, $ a^* $ denotes expressions of the form $ \emptyset, a, aa, aaa, \ldots $

The regular expression in question denotes all sequences (of positive length) where each member of the sequence is one of the 10 digits. It doesn't make sense to call that set of sequences because it contains leading zeroes, e.g. it contains $ 01, 001, 0001 $, all of which correspond to the natural number 1.

Comment: I think you mean Kleene star, not Klein star.